# NET 4.5 HttpClient send cookie anyway (despite changed domain)

Tags: cookies, dns, httpclient, handler, cookiecontainer

I have created an HttpClient in C#

```
                Client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

The handler is this

```
   var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            CookieContainer = CookieContainer,
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
        };
```

I send some requests in a site, let's say it is xyzevents.com. I receive my responses normally, I store some cookies I receive from "Set Cookie:*" commands, everything works good.

However, after this I try to communicate with the site xyz.com. In order to do that, I must send my requests, using the cookies I stored from xyzevents.com earlier. The HttpClient can't do that, because it sees the host is different than xyzevents.com.

Is there a way to bypass that check, and send my requests with no problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anyway to "disable" this check. I think it's the `HttpClient` that ends up deciding which cookies should be sent, not the container. And in the end, the security risks that could happen by sending random cookies anywhere are pretty large.

With that, you could easily loop through all the cookies received from `xyz.com`, create them manually with the domain changed but the same values. Then add them to a new collection which is sent to `xyzevents.com`.

Comment: can't think of a way to edit the cookies I receive. especially now that this client is created in a protected request base class.

Comment: @PanosPaschalis You wouldn't "edit" them. You would just loop through the cookies in the first container, then take the value from that cookie and create a new cookie with the correct domain name, add it to a second container. Then assign that second container to the handler.

Comment: Yes, I don't seem to be able to access the cookiecontainer during the code execution, I can only access the HttpClient (Client).